# Proper Promise handling success and error callbacks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I have following service in TypeScript that fetches data from the backend.

As a parameter of function getAllPropertiesByAppId I have a success and error callback.

```
export class PropertyService implements IPropertyService {

/**
 * Get all properties
 */
public getAllPropertiesByAppId(appliactionId: string, success: (properties: Array<IPropertyItem>) => void, error: (error: any) => void): void {              

    //set up createRequestStr and requestInit

    fetch(createRequestStr, requestInit)
        .then<IPropertyItem[]>((response: Response) => {
            if (response.status===401) {
                throw new UnAuthorizedException();
            }
            return response.json<IPropertyItem[]>();
        })
        .then((response: IPropertyItem[]) => {               
            success(response);
        })
        .catch((reason: any) => {
            //error handling
            }
        });
}
```

Then I am using this service in my action creator:

```
 initProperties: (appId: string): ActionCreator => (dispatch: Redux.Dispatch, getState: () => IApplicationState) => {
    "use strict";

    console.log("ShoppingCart initProperties - Request all Property");

    var service: IPropertyService = kernel.get<IPropertyService>("IPropertyService");

    service.getAllPropertiesByAppId(appId, (properties: Array<IPropertyItem>): void => {

        dispatch(new ShoppingCartPropertiesLoaded(appId, properties));
        dispatch(new ShoppingCartPropertiesDone(appId, System.Init.Done));            

    }, (error: any): void => {
        console.log("ShoppingCart initProperties - error:" + error);
        dispatch(new ShoppingCartPropertiesDone(appId, System.Init.Error));
    });
}
```

So when I call initProperties action creator it calls getAllPropertiesByAppId and when everything is fine I will dispatch actions ShoppingCartPropertiesLoaded and ShoppingCartPropertiesDone.

I have simple component connected to store and the component will throw errors when the render method is executing

```
export default class TotalPriceList extends React.Component<ITotalPriceListProps, void> {

public render(): JSX.Element {

    throw 'SomeError';
}
}
```

The unhandled exception ends up  in the catch statement of fetch.

Have I missed something like how to exit promise correctly or even better how to call function/callback from than statement and exit promise, to avoid catch exception from callback in catch statement of fetch?

Thanks very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to catch an exception inside a promise chain, you only have to remove the `.catch` call at the end.

But keep in mind that you will not be able to catch this error with a `try {} catch (error) {}` block. Instead, it will bubble up to the point where you will receive a `unhandledRejection` at the top level.

If I understood correctly, you are passing a callback (`success`) to `getAllPropertiesByAppId`, which returns a promise that calls the callback; `fetch(…).then(success)` basically. So what you experience is completely to the defined behaviour of exceptions inside functions enclosed in promises.

You might want to switch to using promises all the way instead of mixing continuation passing style (callbacks) and promises.

Something like (in pseudo-code-js, not ts sorry)

```js
class Service {
  getAllPropertiesByAppId (appId) {
    return fetch(createRequestStr, requestInit)
           .then(response => response.json());
  }
};

// …

service.getAllPropertiesByAppId(…)
.then(dispatchAllTheThings)
.catch(error => { console.log(…); dispatch(…) })
```

Throwing a exception inside a dispatched component will then be caught inside the `.catch` in the promise chain after the call to `dispatchAllTheThings`.

Answer (score 2):

> As a parameter of function getAllPropertiesByAppId I have success and error callback.

And that's your actual problem. You should *always return a promise from an asynchronous function*.
Stop using callback parameters!

Your code should read

```
/**
 * Get all properties
 */
public getAllPropertiesByAppId(appliactionId: string): Promise<IPropertyItem[]> {
    //set up createRequestStr and requestInit
    return fetch(createRequestStr, requestInit)
//  ^^^^^^
    .then<IPropertyItem[]>((response: Response) => {
        if (response.status===401) {
            throw new UnAuthorizedException();
        }
        return response.json<IPropertyItem[]>();
    });
}
```

This will incidentally solve your problem with unhandled rejections. By not ending the chain but returning the promise, you put the responsibility of handling errors on the caller - as usual. Also the caller is implicitly responsible for anything he does in *his* promise callbacks - they don't concern the promise-returning method at all.

You'd therefore use

```
service.getAllPropertiesByAppId(appId).then((properties: Array<IPropertyItem>): void => {
//                                    ^^^^^
    dispatch(new ShoppingCartPropertiesLoaded(appId, properties));
    dispatch(new ShoppingCartPropertiesDone(appId, System.Init.Done));            
}, (error: any): void => {
    console.log("ShoppingCart initProperties - error:" + error);
    dispatch(new ShoppingCartPropertiesDone(appId, System.Init.Error));
}).catch((reason: any) => {
    // error handling for a failed dispatch
});
```

Comment: perfect that is exactly  what i was looking for! Thanks Bergi!